# Chinese Postman Problem - open walk variation

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, eulerian-path

Consider the following variation of the *Chinese postman problem* (also known as the *route inspection problem*).  Instead of finding the shortest *closed* walk which traverses each edge at least once, find the shortest *open* walk which traverses each edge at least once.

This variation is sometimes more interesting. For example, the length of a minimal closed edge-covering walk on every tree on $n$ vertices is $2(n-1)$ (as every bridge must be crossed twice), but the length of a minimal open edge-covering walk is different for different trees on the same vertex set.  For example, that number is $6$ for a path with $6$ edges, and $10$ for a star with $6$ leaves.

Does this problem have an easy solution, or an efficient algorithm, as the Chinese postman problem?

I'll add that I am not really interested in finding a shortest walk, but rather in figuring out the length of a minimal walk.

Comment: One simple-minded method would be to produce the $n \choose 2$ graphs resulting from adding another edge - one graph for each pair of vertices, then for each of these graphs, use the $O(n^3)$ algorithm for the regular problem. Your solution will be $1$ less than the shortest length of any of these. This algorithm runs in $O(n^5)$ time. Of course, it is highly inefficient. I have little doubt that a $O(n^3)$ algorithm is possible, probably a minor variation of the algorithm for the reqular problem.

Comment: There are several "related" Questions shown in the sidebar (on the desktop version of this page) about the same problem.  Have you identified a novel aspect of the problem to ask about?  It is easy to identify the graphs which have a path that visits each edge *exactly once*.